# AngularJS: how to update key of $scope associate array on checkbox select/unselect?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

my PHP programming return following JSON via AJAX which is being set in a scrope variable `$scope.roleAssigned` which then eventually generates an `Accordian` with a table and checkbox:

```
$json2 = '{"status":"OK","data":[{"label":"Admin","id":1,"rights":[{"id":"1","label":"create","selected":"1"},{"id":"2","label":"update","selected":"0"},{"id":"3","label":"delete","selected":"0"},{"id":"4","label":"lists","selected":"0"}]},
{"label":"Normal User","id":2,"rights":[{"id":"1","label":"create","selected":"1"},{"id":"2","label":"update","selected":"1"},{"id":"3","label":"delete","selected":"1"},{"id":"4","label":"lists","selected":"0"}]}]}';
```

Now on button click I want to send back same data back to PHP in JSON. `selected` field is telling whether someone clicked on checkbox or not. So for instance `{"id":"1","label":"create","selected":"1"}` could be `{"id":"1","label":"create","selected":"0"}`

Is there any Angular Way to update key of scope array on checkbox click? I don't want to generate iterating DOM(jQuery way).

**HTML**

```
<div class="dynamic" ng-repeat="role in roles | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:queryRoles ">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h2 class="panel-title text-center">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_{{role.id}}">
                                    {{role.label}}
                                </a>
                            </h2>

                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_{{role.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body text-center">
                                <table id="roles-table" class="table table-striped" align="center">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Droit</td>
                                            <td>Action</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="right in role.rights">
                                            <td>{{right.label}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input data-rid="{{role.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked="right.selected == 1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Let me know if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can make use of $parent.$index and $index

```
<input data-rid="{{role.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked="right.selected == 1"    ng-click="checkIt($parent.$index, $index, right.selected)">   

$scope.checkIt= function(parentIndex, index, selected){
      selected = (selected === "1") ? "0" : "1";
      $scope.roles[parentIndex].rights[index].selected = selected;
   };
```

Comment: So once certain key is updated. on click a button it will send updated one?

Comment: Yes. We are updating the scope data. it will surely send updated one if you are using same $scope.roles object  while sending the data.